# How to sort a cell after another cell?

Tags: matlab

i have a cell A produced like this:

```
number=[1 3 2 4];
name={'dog' 'cat' 'fish' 'monkey'};
age=[7 9 2 13];
A=[];
for i=1:4
    A(i).number=number(i);
    A(i).name=name{i};
    A(i).age=age(i);
end
```

Cell B is:

```
B={'cat' 'fish' 'monkey' 'dog'}
```

Now i want cell A sorted, so that A.name is the same order as B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the second output of [`ismember`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```
[~, ind] = ismember(B, {A.name});
A_sorted = A(ind);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`intersect`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html) to obtain the indices of common elements:

```
number=[1 3 2 4];
name={'dog' 'cat' 'fish' 'monkey'};
age=[7 9 2 13];
A=[];
for i=1:4
    A(i).number=number(i);
    A(i).name=name{i};
    A(i).age=age(i);
end
B={'cat' 'fish' 'monkey' 'dog'};

[~, ~, idx] = intersect(B, {A(:).name}, 'stable');
A = A(idx);
```

Which returns:

> > {A.name}

```
ans =

  1×4 cell array

    {'cat'}    {'fish'}    {'monkey'}    {'dog'}
```